# React Props - can not get data

Tags: reactjs

I can not use React Props when i am defining a variable like below (var myCheese);

```js
    function TodoComponent(props) {
        return <div>
            <h1> Move Name : {props.name}</h1>
            <h2> Genre : {props.genre}</h2>
            <p>Cheese nameis: {props.nameis}</p>
            <p>Cheese smellFactor: {props.smellFactor}</p>
            <p>Cheese price: {props.price}</p>
        </div>;
    }
    var myCheese = { nameis: 'Camembert', smellFactor: 'Extreme pong', price: '3.50' };
    ReactDOM.render(
        <div>
            <TodoComponent name="Gladiator" genre="Action" />
            <TodoComponent name="Goodfellas" genre="Drama,Gangsters" />
            <TodoComponent cheese={myCheese} />
        </div>,
        document.getElementById('todo-wrapper')
    );
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="todo-wrapper"></div>
```

The one that is for name and genre is working but for cheese is not working. I can not get data from it. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a prop named “cheese” to your *TodoComponent*, but you are not actually doing anything with that prop. You seem to expect the properties of the object passed to the “cheese” prop to be somehow resolved into multiple props “nameis”, “smellFactor” and “price”, but that's not how props work.

You have two options:

**1. Pass each of the “myCheese” properties as separate props**

```
<TodoComponent 
    nameis={myCheese.nameis}
    smellFactor={myCheese.smellFactor}
    price={myCheese.price}
/>
```

…or…

**2. Use the “cheese” prop in your component**

```
function TodoComponent(props) {
    return <div>
        <p>Cheese nameis: {props.cheese.nameis}</p>
        <p>Cheese smellFactor: {props.cheese.smellFactor}</p>
        <p>Cheese price: {props.cheese.price}</p>
    </div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get it working is to change your component to something like this:

```
const TodoComponent = ({
  name,
  genre,
  nameis,
  smellFactor,
  price
}) => (
  <div>
    <h1> Move Name : {name}</h1>
    <h2> Genre : {genre}</h2>
    <p>Cheese nameis: {nameis}</p>
    <p>Cheese smellFactor: {smellFactor}</p>
    <p>Cheese price: {price}</p>
  </div>;
)
```

And the use it as you want:

```
const myCheese = {
  // here Object properties should much your React component props
  name: 'default', // default value otherwise it will be undefined
  gerne: 'default', // same as above 
  nameis: 'Camembert',
  smellFactor: 'Extreme pong',
  price: '3.50'
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <TodoComponent name="Gladiator" genre="Action" /> //
    <TodoComponent name="Goodfellas" genre="Drama,Gangsters" /> // these two are harcoded
    <TodoComponent {...myCheese} /> // here your props will be passed dynamicly
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('todo-wrapper')
);
```

Hope it will help you.